# Meaning of samples in Libsvm dataset format (Mnist in particular)

Tags: dataset, machine-learning, libsvm

I downloaded Mnist dataset from [Libsvm's dataset page](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass.html#mnist).
All samples are like the following:

```
5 153:3 154:18 155:18 156:18 157:126 ...
```

Does anyone knows what that means? `5` is the class label, but what is `153:3` pair for example? Also I couldn't find the meaning from [mnist's own web page](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way `libsvm` encodes (sparse) vectors. As you said `5` is the label, and the following pairs `i:v` say that the `i`-th entry of the vector is `v`. So you would encode a 3-dim vector (a,b,c) as

```
1:a 2:b 3:c
```

Which is inefficient for dense vectors but a good and established format for sparse data. As it is plain text, the storage space is not optimal, but good enough for most applications. Whereas the files are easy to write and to read.